# Intercept traffic other than port 80 and 443 on burp suite

Tags: http, http-proxy, burp-suite

I am trying to intercept traffic on port 8000. For example my application is running on abc.com:8000. I am unable to intercept this traffic on burp suite. How can I intercept this traffic in Burp?

Comment: Do you mean redirect by any chance? Or block? And what OS is used?

Comment: I want to capture all the traffic like we do on port 80 in burpsuite. I am using windows

Comment: You just need to point your browser to the Burp Suite which listens by default on port 8080 and it will intercept the traffic destined for abc.com:8000.

Comment: @ void_in I have tried this already. It doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work". Do you mean you can't access the site on :8000 or that the requests don't show up in Burp?

Comment: I can access the site but the traffic is not intercepted by Burp. Requests don't show up

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of your browser's proxy settings (redact exact host/domain names if needed). Unless you configured Burp for invisible proxying - in which case it needs to know what specific ports to listen on - a proxy that captures traffic to `https://abc.com:443` should also capture traffic to `https://abc.com:8000` (or the plain HTTP equivalents). The only other thing I can think of is that the server might be on the machine or local network, and your browser is configured to bypass proxies for local requests, which is also easy to fix

Answer (score 3):

In the screenshots below, I've assumed you want to intercept traffic at port 8080 (which is not the default port for the http protocol).

Start burpsuite and enable it to start intercepting network traffic from your machine by clicking on the "intercept"button as shown in the screenshot here:

[image]

Next, configure your browser to use burpsuite as the network proxy, see the config for Firefox, the configuration is similar for other browsers:
[image]

If you have traffic flowing via some other port number then change to it from 8080. Otherwise, you need to use the port no which you have chosen. In case you need the proxy for other protocols such as intercepting SSL traffic, then enable proxy for other protocols too.

As soon as you change the proxy config, all network traffic will start appearing in burpsuite for interception and modifications.